# Pct_change return error while calculating weekly return

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm using the following code to calculate weekly returns:

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'price': np.arange(100)}).set_index(pd.date_range('2015', periods = 100, freq = 'B')) 

df.price.pct_change(periods = 1, freq = 'W')
```

I got an error as:

> ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

I tried to change the freq to other options like "M" for month and "A" for annual, and none of these work, it seems the only value work is 'B'.

How can I get this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df.resample("W").ffill().pct_change(periods=1)`

According to this link https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pct_change.html:

> *periods : int, default 1*
>
> Periods to shift for forming percent change.
>
> *freq : DateOffset, timedelta, or offset alias string, optional*
>
> Increment to use from time series API (e.g. ‘M’ or BDay()).

If you want to know what freq values are able, you can see it here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects

Edit: I have read your question once again and I have noticed that "weekly returns" are the key to your task. So ffill will not be a kind of solution you are looking for. More probably, you would like to calculate a total sum for each business 6-day week, so "sum" should be more suitable, so here:

1) `df.resample("W").sum():`

```
            price
2015-01-04      1
2015-01-11     20
2015-01-18     45
2015-01-25     70
2015-02-01     95
2015-02-08    120
2015-02-15    145
2015-02-22    170
2015-03-01    195
2015-03-08    220
2015-03-15    245
2015-03-22    270
2015-03-29    295
2015-04-05    320
2015-04-12    345
2015-04-19    370
2015-04-26    395
2015-05-03    420
2015-05-10    445
2015-05-17    470
2015-05-24    294
```

2) then applying `pct_change(period=1)` we would like to highlight change between each rows (please be aware that `periods=1` here is redundant: we can use only `pct_change()`):

```
                price
2015-01-04        NaN
2015-01-11  19.000000
2015-01-18   1.250000
2015-01-25   0.555556
2015-02-01   0.357143
2015-02-08   0.263158
2015-02-15   0.208333
2015-02-22   0.172414
2015-03-01   0.147059
2015-03-08   0.128205
2015-03-15   0.113636
2015-03-22   0.102041
2015-03-29   0.092593
2015-04-05   0.084746
2015-04-12   0.078125
2015-04-19   0.072464
2015-04-26   0.067568
2015-05-03   0.063291
2015-05-10   0.059524
2015-05-17   0.056180
2015-05-24  -0.374468
```

If you would like to highlight pct change between two rows, three, ..., n rows, you need to customize `periods` keyword:

```
df.resample("W").sum().pct_change(periods=2)

2015-01-04        NaN
2015-01-11        NaN
2015-01-18  44.000000
2015-01-25   2.500000
2015-02-01   1.111111
2015-02-08   0.714286
2015-02-15   0.526316
2015-02-22   0.416667
2015-03-01   0.344828
2015-03-08   0.294118
2015-03-15   0.256410
2015-03-22   0.227273
2015-03-29   0.204082
2015-04-05   0.185185
2015-04-12   0.169492
2015-04-19   0.156250
2015-04-26   0.144928
2015-05-03   0.135135
2015-05-10   0.126582
2015-05-17   0.119048
2015-05-24  -0.339326
```

Resample().sum() is important when you would like to consider total weeks tendencies. But maybe you want to highlight some other tendencies of growth. So here we use ffill() that fills "empty" row with previous value.

1) df.resample("W").ffill()

```
            price
2015-01-04      1
2015-01-11      6
2015-01-18     11
2015-01-25     16
2015-02-01     21
2015-02-08     26
2015-02-15     31
2015-02-22     36
2015-03-01     41
2015-03-08     46
2015-03-15     51
2015-03-22     56
2015-03-29     61
2015-04-05     66
2015-04-12     71
2015-04-19     76
2015-04-26     81
2015-05-03     86
2015-05-10     91
2015-05-17     96
2015-05-24     99
```

You may notice that those rows represent days of weeks that we have not used in "df". They mostly take values from the first day preceding the date in the row:
2015-01-04 from 2015-01-02
2015-01-11 from 2015-01-09, etc.

2) `df.resample("W").ffill().pct_change()`

```
               price
2015-01-04       NaN
2015-01-11  5.000000
2015-01-18  0.833333
2015-01-25  0.454545
2015-02-01  0.312500
2015-02-08  0.238095
2015-02-15  0.192308
2015-02-22  0.161290
2015-03-01  0.138889
2015-03-08  0.121951
2015-03-15  0.108696
2015-03-22  0.098039
2015-03-29  0.089286
2015-04-05  0.081967
2015-04-12  0.075758
2015-04-19  0.070423
2015-04-26  0.065789
2015-05-03  0.061728
2015-05-10  0.058140
2015-05-17  0.054945
2015-05-24  0.031250
```

Bearing in mind the above, we can use other frequencies, like monthly:

```
df.resample("M").sum().pct_change()

               price
2015-01-31       NaN
2015-02-28  1.727273
2015-03-31  0.833333
2015-04-30  0.419048
2015-05-31 -0.209884
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Resample could do the job. But what does the freq and periods mean in the pct_change function

Comment: Thanks for your reference! can you give an working example, as you see, I tried 'M' and it didn't work.

Comment: @Jason I have updated my answer. Sorry for the delay.